# Swift UI - I am trying to change the background. It is giving me an error under the function buttonPressed()

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, applescript

This is a project that I am working on that basically will allow me to have a welcome page. Once you click on 'click here' the button pressed should make the a new background filled with a new color(Creating a new scene)... which I will hopefully add more to later.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // defined global variables in a function
    @State var backgroundColor: Color = Color.red
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // background called
            backgroundColor
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            // content
            contentLayer
            }
        }

    var contentLayer: some View {
            // content
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome to newsapptest!")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                
                Button(action: {
                    buttonPressed()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Click here to continue to the app!")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.black)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    func buttonPressed() {
        backgroundColor = .blue
```

backgroundColor = .blue is giving me an issue saying that it is not in my scope. How can I fix this?

}

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you format your code (select and use `ctrl-i`), you'll see that your `buttonPressed` function is actually *outside* of your `ContentView` struct. Move it inside, and it will compile correctly:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    // defined global variables in a function
    @State var backgroundColor: Color = Color.red
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // background called
            backgroundColor
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            // content
            contentLayer
        }
    }
    
    var contentLayer: some View {
        // content
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome to newsapptest!")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            Button(action: {
                buttonPressed()
            }, label: {
                Text("Click here to continue to the app!")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            })
        }
    }
    
    func buttonPressed() {
        backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @jnpdx. Also I have it so that the background changes color now, but I thought that it would put a new scene over that. How do I create a new scene that happens after my button that  I created is clicked?

Comment: You'll want to research "NavigationView" and "NavigationLink" if you want to present a new screen.

Comment: how do I go there, or do I have to add it through my code?

Comment: `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` are types you'll use in your code. You might want to check out the Apple SwiftUI tutorials or Hacking With Swift. For example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/216/complete-guide-to-navigationview-in-swiftui

Comment: Thank you so much @jnpdx I really appreciate your help with this as I am a total newbie to this type of thing.

Comment: If this answered your question about the compilation error, you can mark it as correct/accepted with the green check mark.